# Where does Laravel store configuration for memcached session driver?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, memcached

The Laravel docs specify that you can enable memcached as a session handler in `app/config/session.php`; however, it does not specify where memcached itself is configured (such as the servers to use).

I see that you can configure memcached in `app/config/cache.php`, but I don't know if that's used just for the Cache driver or for the session handler as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the config in `app/config/cache.php` for your cache drivers is used for session driver as well.

Take a look at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/SessionManager.php`. The method that creates an instance of the Memcached session driver is this one

```
/**
 * Create an instance of the Memcached session driver.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Session\Store
 */
protected function createMemcachedDriver()
{
    return $this->createCacheBased('memcached');
}
```

That method is calling this other method in the same file

```
/**
 * Create an instance of a cache driven driver.
 *
 * @param  string  $driver
 * @return \Illuminate\Session\Store
 */
protected function createCacheBased($driver)
{
    return $this->buildSession($this->createCacheHandler($driver)); //$driver = 'memcached'
}
```

Which is calling this other method in the same file

```
/**
 * Create the cache based session handler instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $driver
 * @return \Illuminate\Session\CacheBasedSessionHandler
 */
protected function createCacheHandler($driver)
{
    $minutes = $this->app['config']['session.lifetime'];

    return new CacheBasedSessionHandler($this->app['cache']->driver($driver), $minutes);
}
```

There you can see: `this->app['cache']->driver($driver)` which is actually getting your cache driver from the IoC container